# Hololens 2 emulator not responding to keyboard and mouse input

Tags: hololens-emulator

Using version 10.0.22621.1263 Windows 10.

Connected to the internet successfully. Opens up fine. Strangely the microphone works and can produce mic input commands. However, no other input data seems to be flowing through.

How can I fix?

I have ensured HyperV is active

I have turned the firewall off

Not sure what I can do too fully diagnose the issue